# Why console gives me "Unable to find jdbc"

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, maven, jdbc

I am developing an app in Eclipse. That is maven project. I want to work with phpMyAdmin MySqlDatabase. I made a folder META-INF in src-main-resources and in that folder I made context.xml file. This is my context.xml file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context reloadable="true">
<Resource name="jdbc/mysql" auth="Container"   type="javax.sql.DataSource"
    driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=utf8&amp;"
username="root" password="" maxActive="20" maxIdle="10" maxWait="-1" />
</Context>
```

And in src-main-java I made package in which I made DAO class, and this is my DAO class:

```
public class OsobaDAO {
    private static String INSERTOSOBA = "INSERT INTO osoba (ime, prezime, JMBG) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
    private static String DELETEOSOBA = "DELETE  FROM osoba WHERE idosoba = ?";
    private static String SELECTBYID = "SELECT * FROM osoba WHERE idosoba = ?"; private static String GETLASTNOSOBA = "SELECT * FROM osoba ORDER BY idosoba DESC LIMIT ? ";
    private DataSource ds;

    public OsobaDAO(){
        try {
            InitialContext cxt = new InitialContext();
            if ( cxt == null ) { 
            } 
            ds = (DataSource) cxt.lookup( "java:/comp/env/jdbc/mysql" ); 
            if ( ds == null ) { 

            }       
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void insertOsoba(Osoba osoba){
        Connection con = null;
        java.sql.PreparedStatement pstm = null;
        try {
            con = ds.getConnection();
            pstm = con.prepareStatement(INSERTOSOBA);
            pstm.setString(1, osoba.getIme());
            pstm.setString(2, osoba.getPrezime());
            pstm.setString(3, osoba.getJMBG());
            pstm.execute();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Error connecting!");
        }
        try {
            con.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Also, I have a jsp file where I am testing this method insert from DAO:

```
<% OsobaDAO od = new OsobaDAO();

Osoba o = new Osoba("Pera", "Peric", "1111111111111");

// poziv metode
od.insertOsoba(o);
 %>
```

When I run program I have this error:

```
INFO: Server startup in 5862 ms
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [jdbc/mysql] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [jdbc].
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:817)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:159)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:827)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:159)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:827)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:173)
    at org.apache.naming.SelectorContext.lookup(SelectorContext.java:163)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
    at dao.OsobaDAO.<init>(OsobaDAO.java:25)
    at org.apache.jsp.test_jsp._jspService(test_jsp.java:123)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:443)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:783)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:745)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Nov 22, 2016 2:00:13 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/DaoWithMaven] threw exception [java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at dao.OsobaDAO.insertOsoba(OsobaDAO.java:38)
    at org.apache.jsp.test_jsp._jspService(test_jsp.java:128)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:443)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:783)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:745)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Could anyone helps me?

Comment: try cxt.lookup( "java:jdbc/mysql" );

Comment: Nope, again the same...

Comment: have you added the MySQLDatabase connector in your lib.Please check it.if not then add the database connector jar in your lib

Comment: I added mysql connector in tomcat lib, in JDK lib and in maven dependency.

Answer (score 0):

@Atletica use the this link it will be of great help, if the answer will be ok please vote https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html

Comment: Am assuming your application is a web based?

Comment: if so you need to add some configuration in web.xml

Comment: Yes,it is, it is maven project but web based

Comment: <Resource name="jdbc/myoracle" auth="Container"
              type="javax.sql.DataSource" driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
              url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:1521:mysid"
              username="scott" password="tiger" maxActive="20" maxIdle="10"
              maxWait="-1"/>

Comment: Where is that tomcat config file?

Comment: in simple the link I sent you explains everything

Comment: apache-tomcat-8.0.26-windows-x86\apache-tomcat\config    look for context.xml

Comment: open the context.xml and add that code inside <Context> </Context> but should match with your db config and mysql driver

Comment: make sure after that you restart your tomcat:NB datasource is detected when you run your code from browser (container which is tomcat) not java console as you are doing

Comment: make sure after that you restart your tomcat:NB datasource is detected when you run your code from browser (container which is tomcat) not java console as you are doing

Comment: Kindly follow up the link I sent you earlier its working on me so I dont know y it is not on your side,hv u added mysql lib in your pom?

Comment: Yes, I added mysql dependency in my pom

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are deploying your application as war file, you could add an XML file named application.xml to the following directory:

$CATALINA_BASE/conf/Catalina/localhost/application.xml

Inside this file you can configure your database as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Context path="/application"><Resource name="jdbc/mysql" auth="Container"   type="javax.sql.DataSource"
driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database?autoReconnect=true" username="root" password="test" maxActive="20" maxIdle="10" maxWait="-1" /> </Context>
```

With this config only, the application.war is able to use this pool. If you want the pool to be used serverwide you should configure it inside server.xml.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is your problem:

> In individual files (with a ".xml" extension) in the $CATALINA_BASE/conf/[enginename]/[hostname]/ directory. The context path and version will be derived from the base name of the file (the file name less the .xml extension). **This file will always take precedence over any context.xml file packaged in the web application's META-INF directory.**

(quotation from [tomcat.apache.org](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html))

Comment: So, what should I do then?

Comment: Do have a look within your `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/...` directory and if there's an other/older `context.xml`, then delete it and try it once more afterwards (**backup your deleted context.xml!**) or maybe print out the content of this file here - maybe there's another definition of your resource.